# How to change color of text and icon of Sub-Menu attached to Navigation view?

Tags: android, xml, menu, navigation-drawer, submenu

I am trying to figure out how I can change color of sub-menu items which is actually attached to navigation view. Following codes are actually from default template of Navigation Drawer which is available in android studio.

activity_main_drawer.xml

> ```
>  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>     <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_camara"
>             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"
>             android:title="Import"
>             />
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
>             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
>             android:title="Gallery"/>
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_slideshow"
>             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_slideshow"
>             android:title="Slideshow"/>
>         <item
>             android:id="@+id/nav_manage"
>             android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
>             android:title="Tools"/>
>     </group>
>
>     <item android:title="Communicate">
>         <menu>
>             <item
>                 android:id="@+id/nav_share"
>                 android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
>                 android:title="Share"/>
>             <item
>                 android:id="@+id/nav_send"
>                 android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"
>                 android:title="Send"/>
>         </menu>
>     </item>
>
> </menu>
> ```

activity_main.xml

> ```
>     <include
>         layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
>
>     <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
>         android:id="@+id/nav_view"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent"
>         android:layout_gravity="start"
>         android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
>         android:background="#512DA8"
>         app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
>         app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
>         app:itemTextColor="@drawable/nav_menu_item_color"
>         app:itemIconTint="@drawable/nav_menu_item_color"/>
>
> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
> ```

and I have a drawable file for click and normal color which is actualy used above.
nav_menu_item_color.xml

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
> <selector>
>     <item android:color="@color/navTextHover" android:state_checked="true" />
>     <item android:color="@color/navTextNormal" />
>
>
> </selector>
> ```

So, you can see result image as I attached below :-[image: Color of Sub-Menu Items didn't change]

Colors not working for sub menu, so, what I want to do is .. I want to change color of menu item "communicate" and sub-menu item "send" and "share" as it is working for root menu items

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your submenu needs to be wrapped in a menu & group tag like below. This will allow you to select one of any of the menu items at a time. You can select them by setting the item as checked in your NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/myd1"
            android:title="Nav 1"
            />
    </group>
    <item android:title="@string/nav_item_subheading_app">
        <menu>
            <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/nav1"
                    android:icon="@drawable/myd1"
                    android:title="Nav 1"
                    />
            </group>
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Comment: thanks working.. but I also want to change color of item which is outside group i mean which is used for sub-heading .. in my case "communicate"

Comment: I believe that defaults to textColorSecondary, you could try overriding it for that specific view in your theme.

Answer (score 6):

Changing the color of the header and Subheader in the Navigation View and paste the below code in your **res>values>styles.xml**

```
 <style name="NavigationViewStyle">
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item> <!-- menu item text size-->
    <item name="android:listPreferredItemHeightSmall">40dp</item><!-- menu item height-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#FFB300</item>
</style>
```

NavigationView set the header color as textcolor secondary and subheader color as the textColor Primary .

finally, add this style in the navigationView

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navview"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#022F56"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/sidebar_header"
    app:theme="@style/NavigationViewStyle"
    app:menu="@menu/sidebar_home"/>
```

And the output will be,
[image]

Thats all, happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me! How would you change the color of the divider between sections?